# Getting ZERO_RESULTS Response from Google's GEOLocation in iOS.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, xml-parsing

I am trying to implement google's geolocation using xcode. when i pass the url with latitude and longitude, it returns the following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

But when i directly browse the url. it gives the correct result.
sample url: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=68.56066,76.8803&sensor=true

```
coord.latitude = 68.56066;
coord.longitude = 76.8803;

NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true",coord.latitude,coord.longitude];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];


    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"XML Data is %@",str);
```

i need to get the xml results. Is there any problem with my code. When i check for ZERO_RESULTS in google site. They are mentioning like this..

**ZERO_RESULTS indicates that the search was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the search was passed a latlng in a remote location.**

Any Idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the google's geolocation service then you need get the key for access.

You can get the access key using following url
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Use user gmail account for login. Go to the Services tag in the left side and switch on the place api then it will ask the server name give some server name. I gave http://facebook.com. After that go to the API access tag in the left side. it will show all the enabled services. Here you can get the API KEY look like AIMjkUluYsB1G2t5u5p0IIQmsHgiga5F0-8c. Use that key in the following URL last parameter.

XML Response:
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&oe=utf-8&ll=latitude,logitiude&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

JSON Response
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=json&oe=utf-8&ll=latitude,logitiude&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

example : 
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&oe=utf-8&ll=12.922499,77.639354&key=AIMjkUluYsB1G2t5u5p0IIQmsHgiga5F0-8c

example key is dummy one.Try with your own key.

I tried in my app.Its working fine.